# firebase-queue: handling different types of data

Tags: firebase

I want to process different types of data. I see two ways of doing it:

1. Define different "queue" section for each type of data and initialize individual instance of `Queue()` for them
2. Write rules allowing to store different types of data inside one section

Which way is easier for firebase-queue and firebase itself to process?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in your question? What types of data do  you want to process, and what does the processing accomplish? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's just small simple json objects without big hashed binary data. I'm making some different objects from it and pass results to a certain firebase nodes. Then I have other objects which contains different keys, do the pretty much the same thing and put results to an other nodes. I haven't tried to implement this, but I considering that any of this ways possible. So far I have working code which does this thing for one type of data.

Comment: I think the question here is: since you have working code for one 'type' of data, why doesn't it work for another type of data? Are we talking fundamental data types? Strings? Booleans? Ints? Can you post some code so we can see what you are trying to accomplish? I am not sure if it can be determined if you need to leverage firebase-queue based on the data presented so far; straight firebase should handle it.